# SQL: CROSS JOIN over table partitions

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
session_id | page_viewed
    1      |     A
    1      |     B
    1      |     C
    2      |     B
    2      |     E
```

What I would like to do is a cross join of the page_viewed column with itself but where the cross join is done on the partitions from session_id. So, from the table above the query would return:

```
session_id | page_1 | page_2
    1      |    A   |   A
    1      |    A   |   B
    1      |    A   |   C
    1      |    B   |   A
    1      |    B   |   B
    1      |    B   |   C
    1      |    C   |   A
    1      |    C   |   B
    1      |    C   |   C
    2      |    B   |   B
    2      |    B   |   E
    2      |    E   |   B
    2      |    E   |   E
```

I have looked into window functions today trying to find a way around it but it seems join functions cannot be used. Can anyone help?

Comment: Self INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join giving only the `session_id` as the join criteria:

```
SELECT
    t1.session_id,
    t1.page_viewed AS page_1,
    t2.page_viewed AS page_2
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.session_id = t2.session_id;
-- ORDER BY clause optional, if you need it here
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . you seem to want a self-join:

```
select t1.session_id, t1.page_viewed as page_1, t2.page_viewed as page_2
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.session_id = t2.session_id
order by t1.session_id, t1.page_viewed, t2.page_viewed;
```

Comment: How would I filter to only have distinct combinations? For example, I want A/B, but I don't want B/A.